# Openbabel: Generate 3D depiction?

Tags: software, cheminformatics

The process of creating 2D depictions is explained in detail [here](http://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/PNG_2D_depiction.html). This way, it is possible to create a 2D image via running e.g.

obabel  -O 2d_depiction.png

However, how do I generate a ball and stick 3d depiction (as image) instead?

Comment: Try: obabel -L pov

Comment: By the way, there is a specific [Open Babel forum](http://forums.openbabel.org) to ask such questions..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Babel does not generate "ball and stick 3D depictions" directly, because it's not a molecular visualization program.

That's why we started [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/).

There are a few formats supported in Open Babel to write out 3D depictions, e.g.:

- [POV-Ray](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/POV-Ray_input_format.html)
- [STL](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/STL_3D-printing_format.html) - for 3D printing
- [Point Cloud](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/Point_cloud_on_VDW_surface.html) - outlining the Van der Waals surface

But you can make a pseudo-3D "ball and stick" depiction in the SVG format:

[image]

`obabel [file] -O file.svg -xS`

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend using a visualization software to make sure I get the view angle set the way I want. The only reason we added the `-xS` option was to generate previews for 100,000 molecules in [PQR](http://pqr.pitt.edu/) search results.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks : )
Yeah, I know that automatic 3D structure depiction will most often lead to a bad view angle. But I just need them for quick evaluation of MD results and I am planning to integrate the visualization into the IPython notebook.

Comment: If you're integrating into iPython, you might also want to look at [3DMol.js](http://3dmol.csb.pitt.edu/doc/tutorial-url.html) which will give you interactive JavaScript views. e.g. [py3Dmol](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py3Dmol)

Comment: 3DMol.js how could I overlook that, and I looked for molecular graphics packages a lot. If I could I would up vote two times for that comment : )

Comment: I just tried it and managed to get py3Dmol running in like 2 min.  $-$ _interactive_ molecule visualization in the IPython notebook made easy : )